# How big is a single RAM cell?

Tags: memory, ram

I am studying on my own how the PC works and I can't understand one thing. A 32 or 64 bit processor differs for its ability to allocate 2 ^ 32 or 2 ^ 64 addresses for the cells of the RAM. What I do not understand is how big a single cell is. Does a single cell contain only a 0 or 1 or it is bigger (like 1 byte). And also, is the "dimension" of the word related with the CPU architecture?

Answer (score 9):

> A 32 or 64 bit processor differs for its ability to allocate 2 ^ 32 or 2 ^ 64 addresses for the cells of the RAM.

Basic assumption is wrong there.  A 32-bit CPU operates natively on 32 bits of data at a time.  That is, the internal registers and data pathways are in blocks of 32, so each register has 32 bits, and data is moved around in chunks of 32 bits. With a 64-bit CPU it is 64 bits per register and data is moved around in chunks of 64 bits.

It is often the case that the address bus is the same size as the internal native architecture purely because that's convenient.  However, it is not always the case. Take the Z80 CPU. It's an 8 bit CPU, yet it has a 16 bit address bus.

One memory "cell" contains either a 1 or a 0. It is one bit.  They are grouped into words of whatever the memory interface is, and you access the memory either as whole words, or in the case of a number of chips, as portions of words (many chips have the ability to "mask" the data to work with just an upper or lower byte, say).

Seen from the CPU's perspective a word is the width of its internal architecture, so a 32-bit CPU works with 32-bit words.  From the RAM chip's perspective a word is the size of its data interface, so a 16-bit RAM chip has 16-bit words.

For the best efficiency you want to match the CPU's architecture size and the RAM's bus width.  That could be done either with a 32-bit CPU and 32-bit RAM, or more commonly, by adding multiple RAM chips in parallel, for example a 64-bit CPU and four 16-bit RAM chips - each RAM chip handling a quarter of the data lines.  Of course that's not always possible. Take the good old 68000 CPU. Internally it's a 32 bit processor - however it only has a 16 bit data bus, so can only read or write 16 bits of data at a time. This is often termed a 16/32 bit processor.

Comment: Great answer.  For example the 32-bit x86 can address 48-bits worth of memory using PAE (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension).

Answer (score 3):

A single RAM cell is the understood to hold a single bit, regardless of which technology it uses (DRAM, SRAM, FRAM, etc.). This is different from flash whereby a cell may contain multiple bits thanks to technology advances such as [MLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell).

In modern CPU's an address refers to byte, that is 8 bits. (Things have been different in history, but this is more or less settled now).

Again, in modern 32 and 64 bit CPUs the address and data busses are the same size, so a 32 bits CPU can 'natively' address 2^32 bytes, and a 64 bit CPU can address 2^64 bytes. (A CPU can always use hardware kludges like banking or segmentation to address more memory, but using such a scheme is more clumsy that using just the 'native' address size.)

Answer (score 2):

The question conflates/merges several different concepts.

The address space of a 32bit and 64bit Central Processing Unit (CPU) is typically \$2^{32}\text{ and }2^{64}\$ bytes. Though some machines have used each address to access *words*, which are not bytes, that is much less common in modern CPU's. An early meaning of 'byte' was 'the smallest addressable unit of memory', though nowadays everyone means 8 bits.

A key characteristic is the memory address itself will be 32bits or 64bits, and hence could access upto \$2^{32}\text{ and }2^{64}\$ units of memory, bytes.

A simple view is a 32bit bit processor typically operates on 32bits of data, and a 64bit CPU acts on 64 bit data. That is not exactly true on modern CPUs. For example, all higher-end 32bit CPUs can operate on 64bit floating point numbers, and some have support for 64bits or more to be operated upon in one operation. Also, most CPUs can act upon smaller units, such as 8 or 16 bits. So it is somewhat more subtle, but the simple model is convenient.

Another approximation is a 32bit CPU retrieves 32bits of data at a time, and a 64bit CPU retrieves 64bits of data at a time, from memory. That is a bit too simple for several reasons. The simplest is, memory systems are decoupled from the CPU by a memory controller, which may retrieve memory in larger units. So a CPU's memory controller might retrieve 128 bits in one read from memory. Even MCU's like ARM's 32bit Cortex-M (about as simple as ARM design) may be implemented with wide reads, say 64 or 128bit, from program memory.

Finally, a 64bit CPU may be able to handle 64 bit addresses, however, they might not implement a 64bit address bus. \$2^{64}\$ is \$1.8\cdot10^{19}\$ units of addressable memory (bytes) which is unlikely to be practical, so instead the physical address bus may be much smaller, i.e. only 40+ bits.

So , as a 'simplification' a 32bit CPU handles 32bit addresses and data, and a 64bit CPU handles 64bit addresses and data, however, reality is more subtle and sophisticated.

BTW - a 'cell' is usually interpreted as a unit of storage, and is one bit in most storage technologies. These are organised into larger units, for example bytes, because it is more convenient to address and retrieve larger units of data.

Answer (score 1):

In 2018 a single memory cell (1/0) is around 40nm^2, but this size varies depending on the manufacturer and technology used.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE :-) Although the title of the question is ambiguous, I believe you have misunderstood the details of the question. The OP was not asking about it *physical* size. Instead they were asking about what a single RAM cell can *hold*. Quoting from the question: "*What I do not understand is how big a single cell is. Does a single cell contain only a 0 or 1 or it is bigger (like 1 byte). And also, is the "dimension" of the word related with the CPU architecture?*" As you see, those points are not addressed in your answer, but they have been addressed in the other answers.

Comment: I’ll give you a +1 for effort though since you did answer the question and OP was not clear about _size_.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the cell depends on the technology there are two main types that are used in modern processors:

### Sizes and Types

The first is SRAM, it requires more transistors (and is only made of transistors), hence it requires more size and more power. It also puts off more heat. The advantage is it keeps it's state as long as it has power and does not need to be refreshed. It is also much faster than other types of ram. For this reason it is mainly used in processors and buffers.

The second is DRAM it is made from a capacitor and a transistor, less size, less power. The problem with this is the capacitor bleeds a very small amount of current, and loses its state after a given amount of time.

[image]
Source: [Overview of Emerging Non-volatile Memory Technologies](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265727614_Overview_of_Emerging_Non-volatile_Memory_Technologies/figures?lo=1)

This shows the relative sizes of the RAM's, an single bitcell of SRAM as of 2014 and a [10nm process can be 0.014um^2](https://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1328866) a DRAM cell for the same process would be roughly 6 times smaller.

[image]
Source: https://www.quora.com/Will-CPU-chips-contain-the-entire-RAM-in-the-future

### Addressing and Control

The hardware for DRAM and SRAM are simmilar in nature, both need row and column addressing to select the bits, each bit is then read to a buffer. Then the entire buffer can be read to wherever it needs to go. The difference is the DRAM control stops operations and refreshes an entire cell by reading the contents and then writing them back to prevent information loss from the leakage in capacitors.

[image]
Source: http://www.primrosebank.net/computers/mtx/components/memory/dram/dram.htm

[image]
Source: [Design of low power and high read stability 8T-SRAM memory based on the modified Gate Diffusion Input (m-GDI) in 32 nm CNTFET technology](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002626921500230X)

### Future memory types

There are also other types of memory that are not mainstream that have advantages of size and speed over current technologies and some tradeoffs.
[image]
Source: [Slide 20](https://slideplayer.com/slide/10013387/)